# JPA/Criteria API - NotLike

Tags: oracle, jpa-2.0, predicate

I want to use Predicate notLike(Expression x, String pattern) to replace the following query:

```
select * from mytable
where mytable.myParameter not in ('ABC%','XYZ');
```

But when I execute my query using the following predicate:

```
Predicate notLike = builder.notLike(fromMyTable.get(MyTable_.myParameter), "ABC%|BCD");
```

is not working.

But if I create 2 predicates for the both strings: "ABC%" and "XYZ" is working.

Is my pattern written wrong or where is the problem? I tried to change the pattern in many ways but is still not working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL `A not in (X,Y,Z)` predicate is a shortcut for the following condition:

```
A <> X AND A <> Y AND A <> Z
```

this condition uses "not equal" operators, which compare operands for **exact unequality**.
It is not ossible to use `IN` or `NOT IN` operators for pattern-matching.
You must rewrite your query using `LIKE` operator which supports pattern matching:

```
select * from mytable
where mytable.myParameter not in ('XYZ')
  and mytable.myParameter not LIKE 'ABC%';
```

or

```
select * from mytable
where mytable.myParameter <> 'XYZ'
  and mytable.myParameter not LIKE 'ABC%';
```